# react-routerを導入するとcomponentDidMountが呼ばれなくなった

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Reduxのサンプルコードである。[async](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async)にreact-routerを導入しました。しかし、index.jsとroutes.jsを下記のように作成したところ、containers/App.jsの`componentDidMount`が呼ばれずにViewが表示されなくなってしまいました。どこが間違っているのかわかりますか。

index.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import routes from './routes';

const history = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({queryKey: false});
const store = configureStore();

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import { App } from './containers/App';


export default (
    <Route path='/'>
      <IndexRoute component={App}/>
    </Route>
);
```

エラーは特に出てません。

Answer (score -1):

```
import { App } from './containers/App';
```

ではなく

```
import App from './containers/App';
```

ではないでしょうか。ブラウザの Console にエラーが出ていると思います。